# What are the difference between an Angular pipe and Typescript extension method.?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, extension-methods

What are the difference between an Angular pipe and Typescript extension method.?

In my project am using a currency pipe for converting a number to indian currency format, and it turns out that i can achieve the same functionality having an extension methods for number to convert it to currency string in typescipt.

Under which scenario each one should be used.?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an extension method, the expression will be evaluated every time the ChangeDetection runs. (Same as if for example, you insert a function directly in the DOM, or if you use get; set methods, etc.)

On the other hand, in a Pipe (At least in not pure pipes) the pipe will run only when the evaluated expression changes, and not every time the change detection runs (Which is very often).